# Finding substrings with divide and conquer

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a divide and conquer implementation to solve the following problem:

Given a string 'S', find all the substrings in 'S' that contains all the elements from a given set without repetitions.

For example:

```
S = "abcdeabcdeeabcd"; set = {a, b, c, d, e};
```

should return the substrings

```
'abcde', 'abcde' and 'eabcd'
```

On 'x' I got the number of substrings found in the first half of the string, and on 'y' I got the number of substrings found in the second half of the string.

The problem comes with the 'combine' method, how can I get the substring that is in the middle of "abcdeabcdeeabcd"?

My algorithm does the following:

// Doesn't find any substring in these 4 parts.

```
"abc" "deab  "cdee" "abcd"
```

// Merges the first 2 and the last 2

// Finds a substring on the first part and another one on the second

"**abcde**ab" "cde**eabcd**"

// NOW, how can I also get the substring that is in the middle of the 2 previous substrings found after merging the 2 parts?

```
"abcdeabcdeeabcd"
```

Comment: *should return the substrings 'abcde', 'abcde' and 'eabcd'* Why? What about 'bcdea', 'cdeab' and so on (substrings starting at characters 2, 3, 4 and 5 in S)?

Comment: It sounds as if your algorithm is flawed. You can't divide and conquer if you can't divide.

Comment: Seems that it would be best to start with the first letter and construct all possible substrings that begin with that letter (a, ab, abc, abcd, abcde).  That's it for the first letter.  Now, do the second letter and so forth.

Comment: Are you certain that you can have duplicate substrings (abcde and abcde)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it would be best to start with the first letter and construct all possible substrings that begin with that letter (a, ab, abc, abcd, abcde). That's it for the first letter. Now, do the second letter and so forth. –  We have to be careful as we get to the end of the input_str to not go past the end of the string.

Not sure about how to handle duplicates or how the output should be provided.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

/// For each letter in the string, determine if that letter exists in the letter_set.
bool is_string_contained_by_set(const std::string &str,
                                const std::set<char> &letter_set)
{
  for (const auto &letter: str) {
    // if any letter is not in the letter_set, then return false
    if (letter_set.find(letter) == letter_set.end())
      return false;
  }
  // all letters were in teh letter_set, so return true.
  return true;
}

// find all the substrings starting with a given letter up to the length of
// the number of letters in the letter_set.
void find_strings(const std::string &str, const std::set<char> &letter_set)
{
  // create substrings, by starting with the first letter and adding
  // successive letters in sequence up to the number of letters in letter_set
  for (int i = 0; i < letter_set.size(); i++) { // generate all substrings
    std::string substring{str.begin(), str.begin() + i + 1};
    // Check to see if the substring's letters are found in the letter_set
    if (is_string_contained_by_set(substring, letter_set)) {
      std::cout << substring << " \n";
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  const std::string input_str{"abcdeabcdeeabcd"};
  const std::set<char> letter_set{'a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};

  auto start = input_str.begin();
  auto end = input_str.end();

  // loop through each string from the beginning of the input_str
  // find_strings() will only use a substring up to the size of letter_set,
  // so there is no need to check that here.
  // Here, we are just making sure that as we get to the end of str, we don't
  // pass anything beyond the end of the input_str.
  while ( start != input_str.end()) {
    find_strings(std::string{start, end}, letter_set);
    start++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use divide and conquer technique to solve this problem. It can be easily solved with 'sliding window' technique. If you insist on solving it with divide and conquer then you can try this aporoach: add one parameter to the recursive function startPos. check the substring starting from this position and  having length equals to the length of the set and call the recursion with startPos. base will be: startPos == len(str)-len(set)+1